# What does "Inappropriate I/O control operation" error mean when copying files from windows folder to a samba share using Perl

Tags: perl, copy, samba

My question is a little specific, I'm copying files from a windows folder to a Linux samba share using Perl, and periodically, I get an error like this: Inappropriate I/O control operation, which ended up with a corrupted file with the exact same size as the source file. I need to figure out if this is a network issue, or something else. Could somebody enlighten me on this one.
Thanks very much in advance!

David

Comment: Can you share the source code? The error might have to do with how you're copying files.

Comment: It might have to do with the file type. You should, besides showing your code, also say what kind of files get these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently got this error from a Perl script that attempted to access (via Archive::Extract) a non-existent file on a samba share.

Comment: I got this error from perl attempting to close a pipe to a program that expects interactive input. I attempted to write an interactive quit command and then close, but I get this run-time error. Not sure yet what I'm doing wrong...